# Como adicionar parâmetros no WHERE de uma Procedure sem usar IF?

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte Query:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`db`@`%` PROCEDURE `RelatorioComissoesByDate`(
    IN initialPeriod DATETIME,
    IN finalPeriod DATETIME,
    IN FK_Corretora INT,
    IN NomeCliente VARCHAR(256),
    IN Seguradora VARCHAR(256)
)
BEGIN
    IF NomeCliente IS NULL AND Seguradora IS NULL THEN 
        SELECT c.FullName,p.Descricao as DescricaoPedido, S.Descricao as Seguradora, p.PremioLiquidoTotal,p.ComissaoLiquidoTotal,p.PercentualComissao,p.PercentualImpostos, pcss.ValorComissaoLiquido,pcss.Parcela, p.Parcelas as ParcelasTotais, pcss.ComissaoRecebida, pcss.DataRecebimentoComissao,PC.Descricao FROM pedidos p  INNER JOIN clientes c on c.ID = p.FK_Clientes  INNER JOIN corretorausuario CUsuario on C.FK_CorretoraUsuario = CUsuario.ID  INNER JOIN seguradoras S on S.ID = p.FK_Seguradoras  INNER JOIN pedidoscategorias PC on PC.ID = p.FK_PedidosCategorias  INNER JOIN pedidostatus PS ON PS.ID = p.FK_PedidoStatus  INNER JOIN pedidoscomissoes pcss on pcss.FK_Pedidos = p.ID 
        WHERE CUsuario.FK_Corretora = FK_Corretora and pcss.DataRecebimentoComissao between initialPeriod and finalPeriod;

    ELSEIF NomeCliente IS NOT NULL AND Seguradora IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT c.FullName,p.Descricao as DescricaoPedido, S.Descricao as Seguradora, p.PremioLiquidoTotal,p.ComissaoLiquidoTotal,p.PercentualComissao,p.PercentualImpostos, pcss.ValorComissaoLiquido,pcss.Parcela, p.Parcelas as ParcelasTotais, pcss.ComissaoRecebida, pcss.DataRecebimentoComissao,PC.Descricao FROM pedidos p  INNER JOIN clientes c on c.ID = p.FK_Clientes  INNER JOIN corretorausuario CUsuario on C.FK_CorretoraUsuario = CUsuario.ID  INNER JOIN seguradoras S on S.ID = p.FK_Seguradoras  INNER JOIN pedidoscategorias PC on PC.ID = p.FK_PedidosCategorias  INNER JOIN pedidostatus PS ON PS.ID = p.FK_PedidoStatus  INNER JOIN pedidoscomissoes pcss on pcss.FK_Pedidos = p.ID 
        WHERE CUsuario.FK_Corretora = FK_Corretora and pcss.DataRecebimentoComissao between initialPeriod and finalPeriod and c.FullName LIKE CONCAT('%', NomeCliente , '%') and S.Descricao LIKE CONCAT('%', Seguradora , '%');

    ELSEIF NomeCliente IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT c.FullName,p.Descricao as DescricaoPedido, S.Descricao as Seguradora, p.PremioLiquidoTotal,p.ComissaoLiquidoTotal,p.PercentualComissao,p.PercentualImpostos, pcss.ValorComissaoLiquido,pcss.Parcela, p.Parcelas as ParcelasTotais, pcss.ComissaoRecebida, pcss.DataRecebimentoComissao,PC.Descricao FROM pedidos p  INNER JOIN clientes c on c.ID = p.FK_Clientes  INNER JOIN corretorausuario CUsuario on C.FK_CorretoraUsuario = CUsuario.ID  INNER JOIN seguradoras S on S.ID = p.FK_Seguradoras  INNER JOIN pedidoscategorias PC on PC.ID = p.FK_PedidosCategorias  INNER JOIN pedidostatus PS ON PS.ID = p.FK_PedidoStatus  INNER JOIN pedidoscomissoes pcss on pcss.FK_Pedidos = p.ID 
        WHERE CUsuario.FK_Corretora = FK_Corretora and pcss.DataRecebimentoComissao between initialPeriod and finalPeriod and c.FullName LIKE CONCAT('%', NomeCliente , '%');

    ELSEIF Seguradora IS NOT NULL THEN 
        SELECT c.FullName,p.Descricao as DescricaoPedido, S.Descricao as Seguradora, p.PremioLiquidoTotal,p.ComissaoLiquidoTotal,p.PercentualComissao,p.PercentualImpostos, pcss.ValorComissaoLiquido,pcss.Parcela, p.Parcelas as ParcelasTotais, pcss.ComissaoRecebida, pcss.DataRecebimentoComissao,PC.Descricao FROM pedidos p  INNER JOIN clientes c on c.ID = p.FK_Clientes  INNER JOIN corretorausuario CUsuario on C.FK_CorretoraUsuario = CUsuario.ID  INNER JOIN seguradoras S on S.ID = p.FK_Seguradoras  INNER JOIN pedidoscategorias PC on PC.ID = p.FK_PedidosCategorias  INNER JOIN pedidostatus PS ON PS.ID = p.FK_PedidoStatus  INNER JOIN pedidoscomissoes pcss on pcss.FK_Pedidos = p.ID 
        WHERE CUsuario.FK_Corretora = FK_Corretora and pcss.DataRecebimentoComissao between initialPeriod and finalPeriod and   S.Descricao LIKE CONCAT('%', Seguradora , '%');

   END IF;

END
```

Como vocês perceberam todos os `SELECT` são os mesmos, o que muda é o `WHERE` pois preciso que ele adicione cláusulas apenas nos parâmetros que são `NOT NULL` porém a abordagem que eu utilizei ao meu ver é bem amadora, mas não estou conseguindo encontrar outra forma de faze-lo sem precisar repetir código...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma abordagem que você pode tentar é a seguinte

```
SELECT  
    c.FullName,
    p.Descricao as DescricaoPedido, 
    S.Descricao as Seguradora, 
    p.PremioLiquidoTotal,
    p.ComissaoLiquidoTotal,
    p.PercentualComissao,
    p.PercentualImpostos, 
    pcss.ValorComissaoLiquido,
    pcss.Parcela, 
    p.Parcelas as ParcelasTotais, 
    pcss.ComissaoRecebida, 
    pcss.DataRecebimentoComissao,
    PC.Descricao 
FROM 
    pedidos p  
    INNER JOIN clientes c on c.ID = p.FK_Clientes  
    INNER JOIN corretorausuario CUsuario on C.FK_CorretoraUsuario = CUsuario.ID  
    INNER JOIN seguradoras S on S.ID = p.FK_Seguradoras  
    INNER JOIN pedidoscategorias PC on PC.ID = p.FK_PedidosCategorias  
    INNER JOIN pedidostatus PS ON PS.ID = p.FK_PedidoStatus  
    INNER JOIN pedidoscomissoes pcss on pcss.FK_Pedidos = p.ID 
WHERE 
    CUsuario.FK_Corretora = FK_Corretora AND 
    pcss.DataRecebimentoComissao between initialPeriod and finalPeriod AND
    (NomeCliente IS NULL OR c.FullName LIKE CONCAT('%', NomeCliente , '%')) AND
    (Seguradora IS NULL OR S.Descricao LIKE CONCAT('%', Seguradora , '%'))
```

Perceba que dentro do `WHERE` eu checo se é `NULL` ou a pesquisa que você quer fazer.
Se o valor de `NomeCliente`, por exemplo, for `nulo`, a pesquisa da direita é descartada de imediato, ou seja, vai ignorar essa pesquisa pois vai ser `true`. O mesmo acontece com seguradora.

Nesse caso, só irá realmente efetuar a pesquisa quando os valores não forem nulos.

Comment: Muito bom, resolveu meu problema e +1 ponto no conhecimento kkkk valeu